# How can I see the first filters of a convolution layer

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

From this [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1), It was said that if you want to see kernel filter matrices directly, We can get the weight tensor and index into it accordingly. Now I want to see the first kernel of the first filters of my layer.

From the blog, It was mentioned that I can use this `conv1.weight[1,1,:,:]` How do use this for the below model architecture.

```
class Cifar10CnnModel(ImageClassificationBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 64 x 16 x 16

            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 128 x 8 x 8

            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2), # output: 256 x 4 x 4

            nn.Flatten(), 
            nn.Linear(256*4*4, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10))
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a model by:

```
model = Cifar10CnnModel()
```

then your weights will be stored in a sequential model and can be accessed by selecting the first element of the sequential model list:

```
model.network[0].weights
```